# When converting a double to a string, what can the first string character be?

Tags: c, floating-point

When converting a double to a string like so:

```
static void strfromdouble(char *buf, size_t n, double d) {
    snprintf(buf, n, "%.14g", d);
}
```

Which characters could end up in `buf[0]` after the call to `snprintf`?

Obviously, it could be one of the following: `0-9`, `-`, `.` but since we are using floating point math here, there are probably more characters that could end up in `buf[0]` like `I` for `Inf` or `N` for `NaN` and maybe even more?

Is the behaviour of `snprintf` standardized in this situation across different compilers and platforms? If it is, where is the specification, i.e. where can I look up which characters my code would have to be able to deal with in `buf[0]`?

Comment: Here's the POSIX spec https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html

Comment: How are you going to use `buf`? That is, how exactly would your code have to "deal with" characters?

Comment: @stark That spec is kind of dumb. It copy/pastes from the C standard but doesn't include the definition of *n-char-sequence*.

Comment: Kind of a quirky, yet fun question.

Comment: @stark POSIX standard is not C standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When converting a double to a string, what can the first string character be?

Easy to generate `"0123456789-+ iInN"`.  But other `char` are possible, depending on how far we want to stretch it.

> Obviously, it could be one of the following: `0-9`, `-`, `.` but since we are using floating point math here, there are probably more characters that could end up in buf[0] like `I` for `Inf` or `N` for `NaN` and maybe even more?

**`snprintf(buf, n, "%.14g", d);`**

When `n = 1`, expect `buf[0] == '\0'`

When `n = 0`, expect `buf[0]` to be unchanged so *any* `char` value is possible there.

With `"%.14g"` I would not expect `'I'` nor `'N'`, but `'i'` and `'n'`.
`"%.14G"` would produce `'I'` and `'N'`.
A leading `'.'` does not happen with this format.

With other *locales*, (research `setlocale()`), the `'-'` may be something else.  I know of no locale that does that though.

**Other formats**

With other format `"% something [gefaGefa]"` strings:

The first character could be a space `' '` or  `'+'`.  Like `'-'`, that can vary with *locale*.

If a leading `'.'` is possible (I am confident this is not possible with standard formats), others locales may use an alternate such as `','`.

---

With implementation specific formats, any lead character is possible.

With invalid formats, any lead character is possible due to *undefined behavior*.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char s[1000];
  double inf = strtod("inf", 0);
  double nan = strtod("nan", 0);
  snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%g\n", 0.0);   printf("%3d %.1s\n", s[0], s);
  snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%g\n", 9.0);   printf("%3d %.1s\n", s[0], s);
  snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%g\n", -1.0);  printf("%3d %.1s\n", s[0], s);
  snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%+g\n", +1.0); printf("%3d %.1s\n", s[0], s);
  snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%g\n", inf);   printf("%3d %.1s\n", s[0], s);
  snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%G\n", inf);   printf("%3d %.1s\n", s[0], s);
  snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%g\n", nan);   printf("%3d %.1s\n", s[0], s);
  snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%G\n", nan);   printf("%3d %.1s\n", s[0], s);
  snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%5g\n", 1.0);  printf("%3d %.1s\n", s[0], s);
  snprintf(s, 1, "%g\n", 1.0);          printf("%3d %.1s\n", s[0], s);
  s[0] = 'z';
  snprintf(s, 0, "%g\n", 1.0);          printf("%3d %.1s\n", s[0], s);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 48 0
 57 9
 45 -
 43 +
105 i
 73 I
110 n
 78 N
 32  
  0 
122 z
```

---

> Is the behaviour of snprintf standardized in this situation across different compilers and platforms?

Yes.  Compliant possibilities include  `"0123456789-+ iInN"`.  Some compilers may add additional *implementation defined* ones.

---

> where is the specification (?)

Look for the C spec.  Latest is C17

[Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81656/2410359)

---

Details:

```
infinity --> [-]inf or [-]infinity (efga) or uppercase version (EFGA)
nan --> [-]nan or [-]nan(n-char-sequence) or uppercase prefix version

%f --> [−]ddd.ddd,if a decimal-point character appears,at least one digit appears before it.
%F --> like %f
%e --> [−]d.ddd e±dd
%e --> like %e, but with E
%g --> converted in style f or e
%G --> converted in style F or E
%a --> [−]0xh.hhhh p±d
%A --> like %a, but with X,P
```